# Vaadin : how to get return value from javascript methods?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have one JS method `showMessage(message)`

```
function showMessage(message) {
 alert(message);
 return "Your message is " + message;
}
```

I can get arguments of method from my component or UI as

```
    JavaScript.getCurrent().addFunction("showMessage", new JavaScriptFunction() {

        @Override
        public void call(final JSONArray arguments) throws JSONException {
            System.out.println("Getting call JS method " + arguments);

        }
    });
    Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute("showMessage(Hello World !)");
```

So , has there anyway to get return values of JS methods in Vaadin ? If yes , how can I figure it out ?

Comment: I think if we can get **arguments** for js methods , I hope return values should also work. But I have no idea how to get it. Can someone provides me a way ?

Answer (score 2):

no you can't return from there

> Because of the asynchronous nature of the communication between client and server, no return value can be sent back to the browser. 
>   https://vaadin.com/api/7.2.5/com/vaadin/ui/JavaScriptFunction.html#call(org.json.JSONArray)

To get the return value, you have to actually callback to the server (your defined `showMessage` method on server side) from your client side `showMessage` (browser/javascript).  I would assume, that your main problem here is naming them both the same (I am not sure, if Vaadin applies here some package name based prefix, but most likely one of your showMessaage methods overrides the other).

You should rename your client's `showMessage` to something else (`requestMessage` below) and call your server's `showMethod` in there.

```
// client/browser/javascript (remove/rename existing showMessage from your _client_ code)
function requestMessage(m) { showMessage("Requested: "+m) }
// server/vaadin/java
Page.current.javaScript.execute("requestMessage('Hello World')")
```

Comment: Am I need to create custom component(AbstractJavaScriptComponent) for statisfy my problem ?

Comment: I got `SEVERE: (SyntaxError) : missing ) after argument listcom.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (SyntaxError) : missing ) after argument list` .What would be the problem ?

Comment: sir ! Am I need `showMessage(m)` also in my js files ? Now I have created `public void showMessage(final String message) {System.out.println(message);}` on server side.

Comment: no. you need one method to call with your `execute()` request from server to client.  this method on the clients calls your server side method you defined with `addFunction`.